# Call and raise amount in a poker client

Tags: online, software

We are implementing a poker client UI, and unsure about how to show the call or raise amounts in the action buttons so that it does not cause any confusion. I'm not a player so sorry if the terminology used is wrong.

1. Let's say player A opened the betting with $10. Then player B raised it to $50. On Player A's turn, If the call button shows $40, does that unambiguously mean the total bet will be $50 because he already has $10 bet in front of him? Or is it better to show it as $10 + $40? What is the norm here?
2. Similarly, does the amount in raise button in common poker room software mean the minimum bet will be raised "by" or "to" the amount specified?

Comment: If you need help testing I am up for it. I have years of online experience and I am a bad reg in programming. Let me know.

Comment: You could install clients from existing poker rooms and see how they do it. But you're right: it's important to get this right so that players won't be confused.

Comment: 10 + 40 would technically be a string bet in live no? call 40 is fine

Answer (score 2):

1. It is standard to show it as 'Call $40'. This makes sense because it will cost $40 more to call and the previous bettings are already either in the pot or right in fron of him, so the information is already out there. The raise-button should start to say 'Raise $90', which is the minimum raise and can be adjusted later.
2. Player bets $10. Player raises **to** $20.

Answer (score 0):

call $40 is correct.

you usually see something like: call, 1/3 pot 1/2 pot, 2/3 pot, pot, all in.

before the flop some ui's have something like : call, raise 1x, raise 2x, raise 3x, raise 4x, raise 5x, raise 6x

some ui's have slider bars.